# 403 Error When Using Two Different Accounts: Google Analytics API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've successfully managed to pull data using the Google Analytics API with Python for one of my Google accounts. I've used the "Installed Application" client ID for this in the Google Developers Console.

I'd now like to pull data from a different GA account (in a different Google Account). I've followed the same steps as the first but now I'm getting a **403 error** when I run the new script. When I run the [management_v3_reference.py script](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/analytics/management_v3_reference.py) the ouput shows information from the first account! Both scripts are in different folders, have different client secrets and set up in different Google Developers Consoles.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I've been struggling with this one for a while and any help is much appreciated!

I'm running the [core_reporting_v3_reference.py](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/analytics/core_reporting_v3_reference.py) through the cmd line.

E.g.

```
c:\user>python core_reporting_v3_reference.py ga:12345678
```

Comment: Did you remember to change the Profile id?  If you did add a bit of code so I can see what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @DalmTo. Yes, I changed the Profile ID for the second script. Question updated with the code i'm running.